# How to modify OpenInviter to check if those contacts are already on database (and already invited?)

Tags: php, mysql, import-contacts, openinviter

I have OpenInviter running successfully (not for facebook though?)

But I'd like not to send to already members invites o send duplicated invites (but first solves both for me).

How can I prevent that on OpenInviter? By looking at the code.

Have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

you have to build a database table and add every email address that receives an invite to the table. While adding addresses from new contacts, you check the table if it's already existing, if yes, skip it, if no, add it :) So dead simple.

If you don't know any PHP/MySQL i would suggest you to look at the tutorials of http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/ since they are pretty easy to understand.

Comment: yes well, i was actuall asking (long time a go by the way) where is the line that i should place this, i detected it though, but i forgot to close the question... thanks a lot anyway :S